# Intellij: Whats the difference between a module and a directory?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to import a module into a project which has the same name as a module that's already in the project. So to keep them apart I want to rename the existing module. When clicking "Refactor/Rename...", i'm presented with this dialog:
[image]

What's the difference between "directory" and "module" in this context?

Comment: Rename module doesn't change folder name, so two modules will share the same folder structure.

Comment: @y.bedrov OK, and what exactly is the difference between a module and a directory in this context?

Comment: Module is a logical term. It might contain several folderz with different content.

Comment: On the IntelliJ docu, the term is sort of introduced recursively... but thanks alot. Where did you get that info from

Answer (score 2):

a module is like a project, it produce jar file and can behave independently,
but directory is part of a project and use to organize folders and classes.

you can also read this:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html